# update bash in mac os

Tags: bash, macos, macos-mojave

to update the bash i have referred to multiple articles.[this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx)
[this](https://akrabat.com/upgrading-to-bash-4-on-macos/) and [this](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba). Although environment variable are now updated. When i run `echo $BASH ; echo $BASH_VERSION` it prints `/usr/local/bin/bash
5.0.11(1)-release` but still `bash --version` command is printing `version 3.2.57(1)-release`.

Comment: If you run `type bash` it will tell you which bash will be executed when you run your command `bash --version`. It will likely tell you the Apple-supplied one in `/usr/bin` which means you need to change your PATH to put `/usr/local/bin` in.

Comment: Which means your default `bash` (provided with MacOS) supersedes `/usr/local/bin/bash` in the `PATH` definition

Comment: Currently in 2022, homebrew bash is placed in `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`. You can find this via the `which -a bash` command.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are solving this and you cannot change shebangs (because scripts are in shared codebase) or you want permanent solution, you can use following:

**Quick answer**

Open your configuration file for preferred shell. In my case .zshrc (in your case could be different) And export path to your new bash.

Step by step for anyone who has to do it from the start:

1. `brew install bash` (if you don't have homebrew, firstly install https://brew.sh/)
2. `which -a bash` (outputs location of your bash installations)
3. copy new bash location (in my case `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`)
4. `nano ~/.zshrc` (or open your shell configuration in different editor)
5. `add export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` (the specific path differs based on value you got from step 2)
6. <kbd>Ctrl + X</kbd> (to save in case of editor nano)
7. Y to confirm (in case of editor nano)
8. Restart your terminal or run `source ~/.zshrc` (to load changes)